# How to do precision comparison between directories?

Tags: linux, comparison, directory, diff

`diff -r is not enough.` I need comprison of modes, symlinks and like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about diffing the output of `ls -lR` on the two directories?

Comment: Interested idea. I will try it now

Answer (score 1):

I'd say there's no tool that provide that kind of information by default. However, as explained in this [question](https://serverfault.com/q/59812) in serverdefault.com, you can use a command (or script) that prints to stdout the information that you need to compare and use `diff` to compare the output for the directories you want to compare.